# Run multiple Timer tasks with different intervals in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

Say I have the following code

```
 Timer t1 = new Timer();
 t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
         public void run(){
             //TASK 1
         }
 },0,2000);

 Timer t2 = new Timer();
 t2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
         public void run(){
             //TASK 2
         }
 },0,180000);
```

Would Task1 and Task2 run independent of each other or would Task2 hold up the process for 30 minutes?

If the latter happens, would splitting this into two Threads be the only option?

Comment: Couldn't you run this with smaller intervals and just test it?

Comment: @NateWelch, I did. Didn't really work as expected. The whole thing just hung up my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> Corresponding to **each** Timer object is a single background thread that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.

Each of your Timer instances will execute independently.